# Pushwhoosh : Swift Code

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8, pushwoosh

I used below push whoosh swift code but its crashing.

```
        if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")))
        {
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
        }
        else //iOS7
        {
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes( UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge |
                UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound |
                UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert )
        }

     var pushManager:PushNotificationManager  = PushNotificationManager.pushManager();
    pushManager.delegate = self;

    // handling push on app start
    PushNotificationManager.pushManager().handlePushReceived(launchOptions);

    // make sure we count app open in Pushwoosh stats
    PushNotificationManager.pushManager().sendAppOpen();

    // register for push notifications!
    PushNotificationManager.pushManager().registerForPushNotifications();

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Here is Screenshot: [image]

Error: `EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION` for `var pushManager:PushNotificationManager  = PushNotificationManager.pushManager()`

Comment: Did you follow the [the first three important steps in the documentation](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/native-ios-sdk-integration/)? If not, you'll probably find that you'll get back `nil` instead of the PushNotificationManager you're expecting, which will cause this error, as you then try to assign it to a non-Optional variable.

Comment: When testing on a device - I can't seem to get the device to register for Push, meaning that there is no prompt saying this app is using push and in 'Settings -> Notifications' the app don't show up. Any idea?

Comment: @henrik, see my answer below, I used that code and working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you followed these important steps from [the documentation](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/native-ios-sdk-integration/):

> 1. Add Pushwoosh.framework to your project.
> 2. Add -ObjC flag to the Linker Flags in your project.
> 3. In your Info.plist add the following key Pushwoosh_APPID with your Pushwoosh Application ID string value

...then it's very likely that your problem is that `PushNotificationManager.pushManager()` is returning `nil`, which would cause a runtime error when you try to assign the result to a non-optional value.

Comment: 1. Add Pushwoosh_AUTO key to the Info.plist with the value true, this fixed crash. Thanks for link :)